# Is there a way to control Nord vpn via macOS command line or python library?

Tags: python, proxy, vpn

Im writing a python program that performs a redundant task. After the program loops a certain number of times I need to be able to switch VPN servers and start over. So i'm basically trying to use Nord VPN as a proxy in python. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure, but it seems their python API might be doable for the task described. It does enable you to connect to VPN servers through python, so I suppose you can just detect, when you need to change the server, and then just connect to it with their API.

- Check it out here: [NordVPN Python](https://pypi.org/project/nord/)

Answer (score 0):

with the command "scutil --nc stop "NordVPN NordLynx""

Answer (score 0):

To connect and disconnect from NordVPN via the terminal on OSX, I did the following.

1. Setup a manual connection (IKEv2) by following the instructions at https://support.nordvpn.com/Connectivity/macOS/1133051642/How-to-connect-to-NordVPN-with-IKEv2-IPSec-on-macOS.htm.
2. Downloaded and used https://github.com/Timac/VPNStatus (more information here https://blog.timac.org/2018/0719-vpnstatus/)

Then I was able to use `./vpnutil start NordVPN_IKEv2_service_name` and `./vpnutil stop NordVPN_IKEv2_service_name`

I guess it's not specific to python, but it works with shell commands so I guess it will work with python also (by executing shell commands via python).